# Cannot build module "Expected a version of the form 'major[.minor[.subminor]"

Tags: xcode, uikit, xcode7

Whenever I am running project on real device there are errors:
"When I run my app on real device with xcode 7 coming error can not build module uikit and "Expected a version of the form 'major[.minor[.subminor]" Its working perfact on simulator." 
I can not run any project not even new or old.

Answer (score 0):

I solved an issue by reinstalling xcode.thanks